# CakePHP 3.6 nested subquery

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have the following tables.

```
  CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    group_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lastlogin DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    published BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (username)
);

CREATE TABLE companies (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE locations (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    company_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    uuid BINARY(36) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    clock_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY location_company_key (company_id) REFERENCES companies(id),
);
```

Now I want to select all locations that are listed under the companies that are assigned to the logged in user;

```
$companies = $this->Locations->Companies->find()
    ->select(['Companies.id'])
    ->matching('Users', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['Users.id' => $this->Auth->User('id')]);
    });

$locations = $this->Locations->find()
    ->where(['company_id IN' => $companies]);
```

But for some reason I don't get the expected result. Anybody an idea how to fix?

Comment: Please remember to be specific about the problem when asking questions, "_doesn't work_" isn't overly helpful, please always describe what exactly is happening (what results do you get, what does the generated query look like), and what exactly you'd expect to happen instead - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My code was correct, I hadn't had the right sample values in the database

```
$companies = $this->Locations->Companies->find()
    ->select(['Companies.id'])
    ->matching('Users', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['Users.id' => $this->Auth->User('id')]);
    });

$locations = $this->Locations->find()
    ->where(['company_id IN' => $companies])
    ->contain(['Companies']);
```